# How to use chef environment cookbooks?

Tags: chef-infra

I've read Jamie Windsor's blog "[The Environment Cookbook Pattern](http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/)" and understand the concept, along with the concept that cookbooks, other than environment cookbooks, should be in their own version controlled repository, and not in the chef repo directory tree structure. Should the environment cook be the ONLY cookbook in the chef repo directory structure, along with the product? In other words my product should have this directory structure?

```
- Product
--- component1
--- component2
--- chef-repo
------ cookbooks
--------- environment-cookbook
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go this route, you generally don't even need the chef-repo structure at all. Just put each cookbook in its own repo to start with, and possibly try out the workflow with the top-level env cookbook stored next to your app code. I don't do the latter, but Jamie prefers it, see what works best for you.

Comment: I'll still NEED the chef-repo structure to contain my data bags, environments, roles, etc. correct?

Comment: I don't use any of those, so you don't *need* them.

Comment: "You" don't use any of those, but "I" do, so I NEED them.

Comment: Unless you are intending to stop using roles and environments, I'm not sure I see the point in following the more advanced environment-ish and role-ish cookbook patterns. Those patterns are a replacement for their counterparts.